# How get UTC of start of day for specific timezone?

Tags: javascript, date, timezone, momentjs, dayjs

I have to convert 2022-11-29 to '2022-11-29T04:00:00.000Z' it is offset for Santo Domingo Timezone.

But the first problem StartFromUtc is already '2022-11-29T02:00:00+02:00' but I expected '2022-11-29T00:00:00+00:00'.

so the next calculation is wrong too.

How can help?

```js
const tz = 'America/Santo_Domingo';
const startFromDate = '2022-11-29';
const utcdate = dayjs(startFromDate + 'T00:00:00.000Z');
const tzdate = utcdate.tz(tz);
const utcFromTzdate = utcdate.tz(tz);

console.log(
  'StartFrom: ', startFromDate, 
  '\nStartFromUtc: ', utcdate.format(), 
  '\nCreated UTC:  ', utcdate.toISOString(), 
  '\nSanto Domingo:', tzdate.format(),
  '\nUTC For Santo Domingo:', utcFromTzdate.format(),
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dayjs@1/dayjs.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dayjs@1/plugin/utc.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dayjs@1/plugin/timezone.js"></script>
<script>
  dayjs.extend(window.dayjs_plugin_utc);
  dayjs.extend(window.dayjs_plugin_timezone);  
</script>
```

Comment: Why would you expect *tzdate* and *utcFromTzdate* to have different values? The right hand side of the assignments are identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a timestamp in YYYY-MM-DD format, dayjs assumes UTC (perhaps to be consistent with ECMA-262), so it can be parsed to zero hours UTC using:

```
dayjs(startFromDate);
```

To convert it to some other timezone without shifting the date and time values, add *true* as the second parameter when calling *tz*:

```
let tzdate = dayjs(startFromDate).tz(tz, true)
```

Then get the equivalent UTC date and time using *tz* again:

```
let utc = tzdate.tz('UTC')
```

E.g.

```js
const tz = 'America/Santo_Domingo';
const startFromDate = '2022-11-29';
let tzdate = dayjs(startFromDate).tz(tz, true);
let utc = tzdate.tz('UTC');

console.log(
    'StartFrom     : ', startFromDate, 
  '\nSanto Domingo :', tzdate.format(),
  '\nUTC eqiuvalent:', utc.format(),
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dayjs@1/dayjs.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dayjs@1/plugin/utc.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dayjs@1/plugin/timezone.js"></script>
<script>
  dayjs.extend(window.dayjs_plugin_utc);
  dayjs.extend(window.dayjs_plugin_timezone);  
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const tz = 'America/Santo_Domingo';
const startFromDate = dayjs(new Date('2022-11-29 UTC'));
const tzdate = startFromDate.tz(tz);
const utcFromTzdate = startFromDate.tz('UTC');

console.log(
  'StartFrom: ', startFromDate, 
  '\nStartFromUtc: ', startFromDate.format(), 
  '\nCreated UTC:  ', startFromDate.toISOString(), 
  '\nSanto Domingo:', tzdate.format(),
  '\nUTC from Santo Domingo:', utcFromTzdate.format(),
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dayjs@1/dayjs.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dayjs@1/plugin/utc.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dayjs@1/plugin/timezone.js"></script>
<script>
  dayjs.extend(window.dayjs_plugin_utc);
  dayjs.extend(window.dayjs_plugin_timezone);  
</script>
```

Comment: UTC from Santo Domingo: 2022-11-29T00:00:00Z but expected 2022-11-29T04:00:00Z

Comment: `new Date('2022-11-29 UTC')` returns an invalid Date in Safari. It doesn't make sense to load 3 dayjs scripts then rely on the built–in parser.